# Is there a word or phrase for someone who strongly disapproves of smoking, drinking and gambling?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

It would be used in a sentence like this:

> Let's not invite your Uncle Peter. He is (a) ......, you know, and he
>   would feel very uncomfortable among our friends.

I'm not looking for lists.
I'm not looking for phrases that show disapproval of only one of these habits.

If someone strongly disapproves of doing something, it is obvious to me that the person doesn't do it himself, otherwise it wouldn't be genuine disapproval.

Comment: Strongly disapproves of doing it himself only, or strongly disapproves of anybody doing it?

Comment: @jxh Why should I bother about the internal conflict of Uncle Peter, who drinks, smokes and gambles but strongly disapproves of his behaviour?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: It is possible to be strongly opposed to an activity, and not practice it personally, but not have any objection to someone else practicing it.

Comment: @jxh M'kay, but is "to disapprove" the best word to describe this state of mind? I always presumed that disapproval must have some kind of external effect.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: You have to assume people are capable of compartmentalization. Religious convictions may dictate disapproval of activities that you have no interest in enforcing upon others.

Comment: @jxh disapproves of anyone doing it, himself included.

Comment: A _prohibitionist_? The word is most closely tied to prohibition of alcoholic beverages but has a generalized meaning too.

Comment: I think the word is killjoy. "Don't invite uncle Peter. He's such a killjoy."

Comment: You could just say he's moral or he has morals.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Abstainer*, *teetotaler*, *Puritan*?

An *abstainer* is literally one who [abstains](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstain#Verb), typically from some passion or pleasure.

The word *teetotaler* (nothing to do with "tea") comes from the Temperance Movement of the late 1800s, when people claimed to "t-t-totally abstain" from alcohol.  Nowadays, we would say "totally with a capital T", but back then, you would feign a stutter.

The Puritans were [a movement of English Protestants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puritan) who objected to the way the Anglican Church was recreating the hierarchical Roman Church and sought a more personal relationship with God.

Their humane beliefs and passion for education (Harvard was founded as a school for Puritan ministers) have been forgotten, and their preference for plain clothing and their distaste for the theater and public holidays have been unfairly inflated in the public imagination to include a prudish rejection of pleasures like drinking and sex that actual Puritans embraced wholeheartedly.

The historian T.B. Macaulay, who should have known better, wrote, "Puritans disliked bear-baiting not because it gave pain to the bear but because it proffered pleasure to the onlookers."  To call someone a "Puritan" today implies a dour joylessness, someone who doesn't drink not because he has to drive but because he might accidentally enjoy himself.

To me, incidentally, the word "puritanical" describes a thought, word, or deed that might be ascribed (even wrongly as we have seen) to a Puritan.  An actual human being should be tagged as "Puritan" or "a Puritan".

Comment: "Teetotaler" is what came into my head.

Comment: Abstainer is better.  Abstainers are traditionally from the Temperance movement and revile alchohol and related indulgences. A teetotaller may simply not enjoy alcohol or might be a recovering alcoholic.

Comment: "Abstainer" seems like the best so far, along with "Straightlaced", but it is interesting that no one has offered an exact match. *If* the person is of a suitable Christian denomination *and* it is acceptable to add this inference, the "Puritan" is what I would use.

Comment: *Puritan* is ahistorical when it comes to drink; they were [prodigious small beer-drinkers and rum producers] (hence the hefty molasses imports to New England during the Triangular Trade era), and early restrictions on alcohol were intended to address alcoholism and related social ills in Massachusetts— very different from the postbellum temperance movement and Prohibitionism, in which the principal religious characters were Methodist and Baptist, not Congregationalist.

Comment: @Keith -- it's *straitlaced*, not "straightlaced".

Comment: @Malvolio. Never noticed that. UK/US thing? See http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strait-laced?q=Straightlaced

Comment: @Keith -- "Straight-laced and straightjacket are now generally accepted in standard English, and the spelling straight-laced is more common than strait-laced".  The End Times are upon us.

Comment: The suggestions are great, but only mean something to native-speakers or those whose English is quite advanced. Strange nobody's asked that you provide a definition or external references so far. Oh, wait. Someone has, it's me! :)

Comment: Teetotaler certainly doesn't imply that they disapprove of others drinking, or that they would be uncomfortable in the presence of those who do. Plus, the OP said, **I'm not looking for phrases that show disapproval of only one of these habits**.

Comment: @starsplusplus However, this answer does give *Puritan,* and someone with a [puritanical outlook](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puritan#puritan__7) probably does fit the bill (choster's comment notwithstanding).

Comment: @AndrewLeach If it was a maths question and they suggested 4, 5 and 6 for the answer to 2+2, would you chastise me for pointing out that 5 and 6 are wrong? ;) I don't see how the fact they included "Puritan" as well (albeit with a question mark) negates the two points that I was making about "teetotaler".

Comment: *Teetotaler* means one who believes in total-with-a-capital-T abstinence, and not just from alcohol; they would have been the hardliners among the temperance movement. (Carrie — or *Carry*, which was to become her "brand" — Nation may not have qualified since she was all about the sauce.) Admittedly, the word has softened with time (and with the common misconception that the word is *teatotaler*), but it once meant not only somebody who would be uncomfortable in any den of iniquity, but was likely to make everyone else uncomfortable as well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: which is probably why this question is on ELU, and not on ELL.

Comment: @starsplusplus: the fact that 5 and 6 are wrong depends entirely on your definition of `2` and of `+`, which is why analogies don't work.

Comment: As per @AndrewLeach’s comment, ***puritanical*** is perhaps even better than *Puritan*.

Comment: As @Mari-LouA pointed out, this answer could be improved if you added definitions and references.

Comment: @Centaurus -- done.

Answer (score 21):

If you wanted a slightly humorous answer you could make use of ["buzzkill"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buzzkill?s=t)

> Noun: (slang) someone or something that stops people from enjoying themselves

However a suitable adjective might be ["straitlaced"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/straitlaced?s=t)

> 1. excessively strict in conduct or morality; puritanical; prudish:

Comment: Similar to "buzzkill", "killjoy" could be used.

Comment: -1 Buzzkill would not be a word you would use in consideration of the feelings of the person in question as was asked in the text of the question, as it expresses a strong disapproval of his disapproval (a sentiment that was not a part of the requested word). Straitlaced however is a fine word yeah... so irritating that here on english.SE one answer-post is allowed to have multiple answers.

Comment: Struggling to understand your downvote @DavidMulder, whether or not one would use the word in a specific (and not described) extended context does not mean the word is not a relevant and suitable answer. The OP simply does *not* specify the usage context or the range of sensibilities to be observed so positing one that then leads to a downvote seems a little unfair. Depending on the actual social situation there could be many possible answers I see no problem in an answerer providing several of them, especially if the usage is caveated as I did.

Comment: @MarvMills: "*Let's not invite your uncle Peter. He is (a) ......, you know, and he would feel very uncomfortable among our friends.*" was the example context given. How that's not a specification of the usage context is entirely beyond me. Additionally the caveat is that it would be 'humorous' instead of it having an incredible negative connotation which would be a far more appropriate caveat imho. I sincerely do not see how insulting someones opinions can be considered humorous.

Comment: you are over-thinking it. It is a slang word that may or may not be acceptable in the discussion between these two unknown people. They may be chaste husband and wife or they may be two 19 year old frat jocks in a drunken drinking session. Best not to assume a situation.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure if this is in dictionaries (so it might be considered slangy) but it is a term most American-English speakers will be familiar with and means exactly what you're asking for:

> straightedge (*adj*)

Comment: It's found its way into AHD: *[straight-edge: 2. Abstaining from alcohol, tobacco, and drugs](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=straightedge)*, presumably from the punk subculture, which is presumably named for [the song](http://www.pitch.com/FastPitch/archives/2010/10/05/nailed-to-the-x-five-classic-straight-edge-anthems), which in turn… has nothing obviously related to the geometer's tool.

Comment: I wouldn't say _'means exactly what you're asking for'_ because gambling is generally not included in the list of things abstained from in straight edge culture.  See http://sxeworldwide.tumblr.com/Edge-FAQ#sxe02 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_edge

Comment: I've never heard of a straightedge _disapproving_ those things, they usually just don't use them themselves.

Comment: [Straight edge (sometimes abbreviated sXe) is a subculture and subgenre of hardcore punk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_edge) ...

Comment: It does not mean what the OP is asking. My son and many of his friends are straight edge. They don't disapprove of these behaviours by others and regularly attend and host events where others drink alcohol, for example.

Answer (score 12):

The Australian English term for someone like this is: [wowser](http://andc.anu.edu.au/australian-words/meanings-origins?field_alphabet_value=281).

In Australian English this is a very insulting term and should be used carefully.

Addition: [here's](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wowser) the pronunciation. The BrE version is pretty close to Australian English.

Answer (score 10):

The word that immediately came to my mind is [prude](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prude).

Comment: Same with me. But as the MW source you cite states, that first thought was not spot-on.

Answer (score 9):

He might be called a square but this word is not specifically about substance use but rather refers to someone with a normative or conservative way of thinking.  In the 40s, someone who didn't appreciate jazz was called a square.  In the 60s, there were the hippies, and most everyone else was a bunch of squares.   I don't think it is commonly used anymore but my friends find it humorous.

Answer (score 7):

In American slang, they can be called ***goody two-shoes***. They seem uncommonly good and they won't do anything that can be regarded as wrong, immoral or "sinful". This covers both abstaining from and disapproving drinking, smoking, gambling and more.

> *Goody two, goody two, goody goody two shoes*
>
> *Don't drink, don't smoke, what do you do?*

<sub>Warning: It is a belittling term.</sub>

---

> a person who always behaves well, and perhaps has a disapproving attitude to people who do not
>
> <sub>http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/goody-two-shoes</sub>

Comment: Goody two, goody two, why down-vote you?

Answer (score 4):

*Stuffed shirt, wet blanket, killjoy, grinch, spoilsport, Mrs Grundy* and *party pooper* all convey much of what you are after. So does the adjective *prim.*

Of these, the descriptors *stuffed shirt* and *Mrs Grundy* probably convey the lowest degree of intent to spoil the pleasure of others; the terms principally imply a person of conservative, conventional views as regards social behaviour.

Similarly, *prim* means 'exaggeratedly proper', but not necessarily with the implication of possessing the desire to prevent other people having fun.

Answer (score 1):

"Royal pain in the assets" is how I'd likely describe him.  But ["prig" (definition 3)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prig) seems to fit the requirements pretty well, and is probably understood by most in the US, at least.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one of the two below. Which is more appropriate depends on how Uncle Peter actually expresses his discomfort:

> Let's not invite your uncle Peter. He is ***austere***...
>   Let's not invite your uncle Peter. He is ***sententious***...

Only going by the context provided, I would describe Uncle Peter as ***austere***. Its primary meaning is "stern and cold in appearance or manner", but also means "morally strict, ascetic" (source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/austere)).

The word ***ascetic*** is like *austere*, but with the connotations reversed.

> 1 :  practicing strict self-denial as a measure of personal and especially spiritual discipline
>   2 :  austere in appearance, manner, or attitude
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ascetic))</sub>

However, it is a more obscure word than *austere*.

The disapproval of indulgent activity is inherently a personal choice, as the individual believes choosing to do is better morally or spiritually. The word *austere* would give the indication that the individual subjects that disapproval upon others as well. If the individual actively vocalizes the harms of over-indulgence rather than just cold or disapproving looks, then you could use the word ***sententious***:

> : having or expessing strong opinions about what people should and should not do
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sententious))</sub>

You could use the more commonly understood word ***preachy***, but I feel it has religious connotations which may or may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Temperance advocate is a somewhat old-fashioned term, used often about 75 to 100 years ago. Teetotaler is current and applies specifically to alcohol, whereas temperance is applicable to all abstainers.

Answer (score 0):

A word that you might typically use to describe that sort of person while not strictly meaning that exactly is **conservative**.

"He was always quite wild even though his parents were pretty conservative"

Answer (score 0):

I think "Straight Arrow" should cover it.

Comment: I don't think so. "straight arrow" means truthful, AFAIK; doesn't say anything about their capacity for fun.

Comment: From UrbanDictionary.com : Straight Arrow "A person who doesn't use alcohol, nicotine, caffeine, or other drugs. Can also be used to refer to somebody who doesn't party, cuss, stay out late, or engage in other risky activities."

Comment: Hmm, that one only has 46 upvotes, not exactly established slang though.